# Multi entry raffle one win per person

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I have a statistical question. I wanted to know the probability of winning a multi entry raffle with 20 wins and only 1 win per person. Each Person can have multiple tickets.

Let’s assume I have 2 tickets with an overall amount of 10000 ticket entries and 4000 persons joining the contest. With 20 wins but a person can not win twice.

I really failed with my knowledge in statistics.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Best regards,

Mike

Comment: It depends on the specifics of how many tickets each person bought.  Compare, for instance, the situation where everybody buys only two or three tickets apiece to the one where one person buys 6001 tickets and everybody else buys one ticket each.

Comment: Ok let’s assume on average every person has 2.5 entries

Comment: That is the case in both examples I gave!  Besides, your question is fully answered in the duplicate thread.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it